# Sharepoint & JMeter

Tags: testing

Im currently testing performance of sharepoint pages. As a tool to choose JMeter. Wondered write scenarios for testing it. Found that this is done through a proxy server, built-in JMEter. Adding proxy in workspace, but there is a problem. Since I use NTLM authentication, I add to simple test HTTP requests HTTP Authorization Manager, and there all works (for my custom HTTP Requests in a test). But in the proxy it does't.
The [documentation clearly says](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html%20#%20HTTP_Proxy_Server):

> The Proxy server passes on any Authorization headers sent by the
>   browser, but does not save them in the test plan. If the site requires
>   Authorization, you will need to add an Authorization Manager and fill
>   it in with the necessary entries.

I create a proxy, I add HTTP Authorization Manager (or don't, the result is not affected). But when I set proxy settings in my browser, everything stops working. All requests end in a proxy with 401 error (the user is not authenticated), and in IE I see complete silence (blank page). Chrome, like FF, asks the user / password, but when I specify them, can not be authenticated, he asks again login and password.

- [JMeter proxy step by step manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) does not help me absolutely
- Allow anonymous access SharePoint not give any effect at all (get the same 401 error)
- Many hours of documentation and randomly switching checkboxes in settings JMeter had no effect
- Search the forums led me [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197961/jmeter-ntlm-windows-authentication-load-testing), but it doesn't help. What helped author the question, I have already admitted, when I read the documentation
- Blog search brought me [over here](http://zacster.blogspot.ru/2008/03/quick-howto-to-setup-jmeter.html), but the question in the comments on NTLM guy did not answer
- Also found [here is the record](http://erickhaw.blogspot.ru/2010/12/jmeter-stressload-test-for-sharepoint.html), asked in comments author, but little hope.

I appeal to you for help, my colleagues. If anyone has experience with JMeter and NTLM in SharePoint, please tell me how to configure a proxy server. My mind dictates that I am missing something simple.
And 2 more question. What about test requests for large files (500 MB) with this utility? I get requests from the test, but the results files does not written. Oh, and the final question. And what you're testing performance of SharePoint?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @VadimYangunaev it was too long time ago, I just don't remember, sry :)